# JQuery change value of anchor link

Tags: jquery

I have a value coming in from a CMS which I don't have access to and am looking for a jquery workaround. I'd like to target an anchor link based on value and then replace. I know how to do this based on class or ID but I don't have access to edit those.

Here is my rendered html:

```
<a class="searchtitle" href="https://sitname.com">STRONG</a>
```

Would it be possible to target $(.searchtitle) where the value equals strong and replace it with a new value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) Here's a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xvxtqeft/2/)

```
$('.searchtitle').filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).text() == "STRONG"; 
}).text('hello');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use:

```
$('.searchtitle:contains("STRONG")').html('new text')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xvxtqeft/)**

Comment: This will also replace links with anchors like 'VERY STRONG'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.searchtitle').filter(function(){
    return $(this).html()=="STRONG";
}).html("new value");
```